# Should I include terms of agreement and privacy policy in my iOS application?

Tags: legal, terms-of-service

I am developing mobile based social network with backend and I cache some data from facebook. I asssume I should include a kind of Terms of use and privacy policy statement in the application? is it really neccessary? where can I find proper templates for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

It helps you protect against legal consequences. It helps you to limit your damages. It's a legal contract that your users agrees before using the platform.

Comment: THanks, and where can I find sample documents?

Comment: check out any service that requires login, check out facebook, google terms, etc. You can find at the bottom of this page as well `legal` http://stackexchange.com/legal